# How to get the currently focused menu item ID?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2008, menubar

I want to display info when my mouse cursor is on an item in my menu by using SendMessage() to my statusbar. How do i get the current menu item ID ? I suppose they use same ID's as my Visual Studio shows in the menu editor.

I found these on msdn but none of them seems to serve my needs:

```
WM_COMMAND
WM_CONTEXTMENU
WM_ENTERMENULOOP
WM_EXITMENULOOP
WM_GETTITLEBARINFOEX
WM_MENUCOMMAND
WM_MENUDRAG
WM_MENUGETOBJECT
WM_MENURBUTTONUP
WM_NEXTMENU
WM_UNINITMENUPOPUP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the user is moving around the menu you get [WM_MENUSELECT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646352(VS.85).aspx) messages.  `LOWORD(lParam)` will be the id of the menu item *unless* what is currently being selected is a popup rather than an item.

so your code looks something like this

```
case WM_MENUSELECT
   {
   HMENU hmenu  = (HMENU) lParam;
   UINT  idItem = (UINT) LOWORD(wParam);
   UINT  flags  = (UINT) HIWORD(wParam);

   if (flags & MF_POPUP)
      {
      // idItem is actually a popup index
      HMENU hSubMenu = GetSubMenu(hmenu, idItem);
      idItem = 0; // assign an id to the menu, or just set to 0 for no output
      }

   // show menu info on status bar for idItem
   SendMessage(hwndStatbar, ..., idItem, ...);
   }
```

Comment: interesting, but i cant seem to get it work... seems like the ID's are not the same as in the menu editor...

Comment: I tried setting statusbar info with the lParam number, but it doesnt seem to change at all when i move cursor over different items... only when i open new submenu it changes... however, the wParam value seems to change when i move cursor over different item o.O

Comment: sorry, that was a typo, should have been wParam, code is fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using..

```
GetFocus();
```

I think that returns a pointer to the control if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 0):

(maybe not a complete answer, but) Can't you use use strings in the STRINGTABLE section of the resources ?

for example,  for your menu ID:

```
MENUITEM "Your Menu Item...",              IDM_YOUR_MENU_ITEM
```

in the STRINGTABLE

```
STRINGTABLE 
BEGIN
    IDM_ALL_SURFACE_PROFILE_FEATURES "Message1\nMessage2"
 END
```

If memory serves me well, the first part of the string will be the text displayed in the statusbar.

Max.

Comment: I set the strings now in there, but what code i need to send those in my statusbar? its not working by default...